# HTML 5 Video playstate overlay

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a special requirement with html5 `<video>`, I hope, you guys can help me out.

Is it possible to add a `<div>`,`<p>` or something above the html5 `<video> object`?
Plus Trigger the PlayState of the Video and hide it, and show it after the video is stopped?

This is the Poster:

eg:

```
<video width="280" height="158"  poster="img/thumb.png" controls>
   <source src="TestVideo1.mp4" type="video/mp4">
 Get a new Browser my friend
 <h1>Title</h1>
 <p>Some Description</p>
 </video>
```

And is should look like this

Is there any possible way to do this?

Thank You

**Note:**

> I have read this post [Overlaying a DIV On Top Of HTML 5 Video](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16823636/overlaying-a-div-on-top-of-html-5-video) but it didn't helped.

**Images:**

Poster

https://i.stack.imgur.com/vA1zn.png

It should be like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/qsZaI.png

Comment: if you're prepared to use javascript take a look at http://www.videojs.com/ it does what you want and keeps the same user experience across browsers

Comment: Thank you, but I'd like to add a Text on the Player eg. Title and Description. It must disappear when the Video is playing.

Answer (score 0):

You are going to have to use a combination of the canvas tag and javascript to get what you want.

Try taking a look at these two articles for a start:

[video + canvas = magic](http://html5doctor.com/video-canvas-magic/)

[Using CSS3 and Jquery to create a custom HTML5 Player](http://www.inserthtml.com/2013/03/custom-html5-video-player/)