# Can I apply a tint effect using css on a video

Tags: html, css

Hi Im trying to apply a tint effect on a video background similar to applying a tint css effect on an image background the problem is the style wont apply now my question is.. Can this idea of mine possible? is so can someone show me how? since been looking for articles on google and everything keeps on showing me articles on how to apply a tint on an image background

Here is my code somehow:

```
<div class="item" > <video src="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>" preload="auto" autoplay loop muted></video></div>
```

and my css is this:

```
.item{background: rgba(0,255,255, 0.5); }
```

please help thanks
oh btw This is on wordpress

Comment: You mean [something like this answer of mine?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26241019/2930477)