# CSS3 Background Gradient Overlay HTML5 Video

Tags: html, css

I want to apply a CSS3 gradient overlay to a video. I have a feeling this could be to do with z-indexing / stack orders so here is my code.

Div structure:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="gradient">
        <video></video>
    </div>
</div>
```

The CSS I'm using is a background-image radial gradient:

```
.gradient {
        background-image: 
        radial-gradient(
            circle at 36% 48%, #000000, 
            rgba(11, 39, 65, 0.32) 87%, 
            rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0)
        );
    }
```

The styling is applied to the gradient div along with position: relative; and z-index: 10; to make the gradient overlay the video.

The gradient doesn't appear at all - how is this achievable?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Overlaying a DIV On Top Of HTML 5 Video](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16823636/overlaying-a-div-on-top-of-html-5-video)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**2022 update**

We can use the pseudo-element `::after` to display a gradient over the whole image without unnecessary HTML markup. I've also chosen to use the [`aspect-ratio`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/aspect-ratio) property to size the video but feel free to use any technique you like.

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

.wrapper::after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  content: '';
  background-image: radial-gradient(
    circle at 36% 48%,
    #000000,
    rgba(11, 39, 65, 0.32) 87%,
    rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)
  );
}

video {
  width: 100%;
  aspect-ratio: 4/3;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <video>
    <source
      src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/8c/Dancing-for-Food-in-the-Deep-Sea-Bacterial-Farming-by-a-New-Species-of-Yeti-Crab-pone.0026243.s002.ogv"
      type="video/webm"
    />
  </video>
</div>
```

---

**Historical answer**

You must set `width` and `height` to the div containing the gradient in order to be displayed. Then, use `z-index` to put the div on top of the video

You can do it that way :

```css
.wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}

.gradient {
  background-image: radial-gradient(
    circle at 36% 48%,
    #000000,
    rgba(11, 39, 65, 0.32) 87%,
    rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)
  );
  width: 100%;
  height: calc(100vh - 80px);
  min-height: 600px;
  object-fit: cover;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}

video {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  width: 100%;
  height: calc(100vh - 80px);
  min-height: 600px;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="gradient"></div>
  <video>
    <source
      src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/8c/Dancing-for-Food-in-the-Deep-Sea-Bacterial-Farming-by-a-New-Species-of-Yeti-Crab-pone.0026243.s002.ogv"
      type="video/webm"
    />
  </video>
</div>
```

Notice that I've pulled the `video` element out of the gradient `div`, so it can be displayed on top of it.

Hope it'll help.

Comment: Thank you very much - exactly what I'm after.

Comment: You're welcome. Be careful, this is not responsive : you have to adjuste the height of the gradient manually. I think it's possible to make it responsive but it would be much more complicated...

Comment: I'm now finding that is my issue. The video I have is responsive and the height expands outside of the gradient. Would you have any ideas on a solution for this?

Comment: @Filth I surely do, just give me some time :). Could you share the way the video is sized ?

Comment: Thank you - the video is sized like so:     width: 100%;
    height: calc(100vh - 80px);
    min-height: 600px;
    -o-object-fit: cover;
    object-fit: cover;

The parent div has:     position: absolute;
    width: 100%; 

Hope this helps.

Comment: Here you go @Filth :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158863/discussion-between-filth-and-youdeservethat).

Answer (score 2):

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <video></video>
    <div class="gradient">
    </div>
</div>
```

Move the video out of the gradient div, now position the gradient over the video with `position: absolute` and because you have `z-index: 10;` it should cover the video properly.

One issue with this solution that you will most likely run into if you actually give the `.gradient`  fixed `height` & `width` it will cover the video controls and they won't be clickable.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

add a sibling to video make its `position:absolute` and add `z-index`

```css
.wrapper {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    //padding: 20px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-attachment: scroll;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.wrapper video {
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}
.wrapper .overlay {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    z-index: 2;
   background-image: 
        radial-gradient(
            circle at 36% 48%, #000000, 
            rgba(11, 39, 65, 0.32) 87%, 
            rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0)
        );
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="overlay"></div>
    <div class="gradient">
        <video>
          //your video
        </video>
    </div>
</div>
```